# Cleanup of leap motion controller data

Tags: javascript, leap-motion

I noticed that the data I'm getting from the leap motion controller is quite noisy. Apart from the obvious (i.e. position of the fingers), I've encoutered events such as

- fingers moving between hands,
- "phantom" hands appearing,
- fingers disappearing and reappearing immediately afterwards.

Does the API (in particular the Javascript API) provide any means of cleaning this data or is there any other way of making this data less noisy? All of these events can be handled in user code of course, but it seems that having to do this yourself every time would be less than ideal.

Comment: I think at the moment we're left with implementing fixes for this in the user applications. I've done a bit of development and noticed the issues with fingers disappearing and then reappearing causing some problems in my apps.

Answer (score 2):

In short, no- at the moment the developers have to implement the logic for that. Be aware that this might not be true in the future, the API changes fast.

I had problems with this as well, I solved this by using a circular queue with a max limit of (for example) 100 frames. Then I would track the data for just one pointable. I would then filter the data for the conditions I considered to be not normal. For example width, which is very unreliable. I would get the modal value, and accept a +2 -2 range for the modal value. I would ignore everything else. Works rather well :)

In short, as you already mentioned, you need to collect data, and filter out the noise. Tool and width precision will change they told me. Do a search on the forum for isTool and see how others found ways to get 'stabilized' data.

For me the solution was (for what I wanted, which was to track one pointable, and a reliable width):

- Hold a queue of max X items
- Set a tolerance limit
- Compare the data in the queue
- Filter out what was considered noise